# Chrome Extension automation: How to open extension a normal way, not in tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to automate Chrome extension by simulating extension click. What happens is that the extension gets opened, but in a tab. Is there a way to open it a normal way?

Here's my code in Eclipse:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--enable-extensions");
    options.addExtensions(new File("chrome-extensions.crx"));
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

    driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");

    Thread.sleep(500);

    driver.get("chrome-extension://jojhfjndaijp.../popup.html"); 
    System.out.println(driver);

    driver.navigate().refresh();
    Thread.sleep(50000);
    driver.quit();
```

This is how it is opened (in a tab):

[image]

I want it like this, normal way:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to click the extension area using selenium webdriver. If you intend to test the extension then you have to do it using `chrome-extension://jojhfjndaijp.../popup.html`.

At the end it doesn't make a difference because clicking in popup calls the same page(*popup.html which you are opening in driver*) from extension's perspective.

Comment: I agree that calls the same page, but the extension looks different when called normally, with additional features, not just Browse. (

Comment: are there tools to use except webdriver?

Comment: If the requirement is here solely to `Automate` the extension, then unfortunately selenium is only way. Actions can be mocked through accessing popup.html and backgroung.html pages only.

Comment: I am sad and lonely. Thank you @dejavu_cmd_delt.